# Why even Gazebo + ROS questions should be asked on gazebosim.org?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

@nkoenig announced [in this thread](http://code.ros.org/lurker/message/20120925.160824.7c8d5f5f.es.html).

To me, however, since `Gazebo` can work standalone without `ROS`, it makes more sense to delegate `ROS` related question to [answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org). Indeed there have been recently [many questions that are related to `gazebo` on answers.ros.org](http://answers.ros.org/questions/scope:all/sort:activity-desc/tags:gazebo/page:1/) that might have not captured enough attention from people in gazebosim community.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/595/why-even-gazebo-+-ros-questions-should-be-asked-on-gazebosim.org?/) by [IsaacS](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/15/isaacs/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 118 on 2013-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo is a utility that ROS and others use. It's best to keep all questions related to a utility in one place. This reduces confusion, and is cleaner from a project standpoint.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1